# Axure : Create Variable List on one page and take it to another page to populate widgets

Tags: wireframe, axure

I have this data grid

where I want to select the items and take that list of items to other page where I need to populate the Business Process Names selected from the grid in the list box widget

PS: new user to Axure [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axure is stateless, so you will need to use custom variables to make it state-full.

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen quite a tricky topic to start with and to my knowledge there is no straight forward solution to this problem. But let's break down the problem.

I don't know if you have used a table or a repeater.
Have a look at repeaters if you haven't heard of them.
My example is based on two repeaters, one for the selection page, on for the results.

Transferring data from one page to another can be done using global variables.
However storing a whole repeater is a tricky thing.

So instead just store the index of the selected row in a selection-variable.
This is done by updating the repeater if the checkbox is updated. The items status is saved in a separate column in the repeater.

When the repeater is updated onItemLoad is called for every repeater item.
The first of the items resets the selection-variable and then every item attaches its index, if its selection-status is true.

On the second page there is also a repeater with all elements, but on load all elements where we can't find the corresponding index are filtered out.
This is done using the contain-function in the filter query.

Here is the axshare example:

http://cstlzo.axshare.com/#p=home

And here is the source file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tayytafkdiwbgxd/Axure-Populate-Repeater.rp?dl=0